# How to convert String which contains arrays to Vector which can be loaded into a DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, string, vector, properties, save

The purpose is i want to save and load the content of a jTable (DefaultTableModel) into a file using Properties. Saving the contents is possible with this line in the main class:

```
prop.setProperty("extraProfiles", extraRC.saveExtraProfiles());
```

the class which contains the table has a getter:

```
public String saveExtraProfiles() {
    return model.getDataVector().toString();
}
```

The result i get is: [[Zijborstelprofiel - P3A314, Anodisé, 2000, 1], [L-Profiel 15 x 15, Anodisé, 2000, 1], [L-Profiel 15 x 15, Anodisé, 2000, 1]]

Now I want to load this saved string back into the table when reopening my program:

```
extraRC.setExtraProfiles(prop.getProperty("extraProfiles", ""));
```

Now the setter looks like this:

```
public void setExtraProfiles(String dataVector) {
    if (!dataVector.equals("")) {
        Vector<String> vectordata = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(dataVector));

        Vector<String> columns = new Vector<String>();
        for (int c = 0; c < model.getColumnCount(); c++) {
            columns.add(model.getColumnName(c));
        }
        model.setDataVector(vectordata, columns);
    }
}
```

but this throws exceptions: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not a good idea. toString() doesn't emit the content of the vector in a format that is reversible, or even parseable unambiguously. You should choose a more suitable format for that, like JSON or XML. And Arrays.asList doesn't parse your string to make it an array. It just creates a list containing your string as single element.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks! The problem is i'm already using my program for a long time and saving a lot of variables to a file using Properties.\prop.storeToXML(output, ""); Now i'm expanding the program and want to save the contents of the jTable also to this file. So this is why i choose to save the vector as a String hopeing to parse the  string afterwards back to a Vector. Do you have a workaround for this?

Comment: You can still store it as a String in the same file, but not just using toString to generate that string. Instead, use a JSON or XML marshaller. That will generate a string that is parseable.